# Regular expression to match pipes with no sub-string between them

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, replaceall

Can somebody please share the regex to match only the Pipes with no sub string between them?

For example:

ABC, XYZ, |||,|||||, ||G|F|,1|2,||||, R|T|Y

I only want ||| and ||||| and |||| selected.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:

Using the help of people in the comments below. I have a regex that partially works (?<=^|,\s)?(\|+)(?=,|,$)

However, this selects the | after F in sub string ||G|F|

Is there anyway to modify this regex to only select pipes between commas that do not have strings between them?

Comment: Something like `(?:^|,)\s*(\|+)(?:,|$)`? You can access the pipes using the first capturing group. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ca3kRR/1

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. But the regex seems to be capturing the leading and trailing commas as well. I just want to select the pipes @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: As I said, you can find only the pipes in group #1. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the regex engine that you're using so I can't tell if there's a better option (Lookarounds, `\K`, etc.) that would work for you. This one is the generic solution that should work with almost any regex flavor.

Comment: I am using this in Nifi Replace Text processor, which uses the JAVA regular expressions @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: In `, ||G|F|,1|2,||||,` you are capturing only `||||`. Why not `||` at the beginning of that string, as those two pipes do not have a substring between them?

Comment: Well, if it's always going to be zero or one space after the comma, I believe that `(?<=^|,\s?)(\|+)(?=,|$)` should work in Java. If there can be any number of spaces, I don't think that's going to be possible without capturing groups (which aren't that bad if you know how to use them).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Essentially I am looking to capture pipes between commas with no sub string between them. So in this instance the || at the beginning of ||G|F| does not count

Comment: @brandonlee Well, then the syntax is not supported by your regex engine. Use capturing groups. Stay on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given the language you are using. If it supports \K, as does PCRE (PHP) and others, you extract substrings that match the following regular expression.

```
(?:^|,)[^,|]*\K\|{2,}(?=[^,|]*(?:,|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E195Zj/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?:^|,)     # match start of string or ',' in a non-capture group
[^,|]*      # match 0+ chars other than ',' and '|'
\K          # forget everything matched so far
\|{2,}      # match 2+ '|'  
(?=
  [^,|]*    # match 0+ chars other than ',' and '|'
  (?:,|$)   # match a comma or the end of the string 
)           # end non-capture group
```

Taken from the demo link, "\K resets the starting point of the reported match."

If you wish to match single pipes between commas (e.g, `,1|2,`) change `{2,}` to `+`.

If `\K` is not supported but a capture group could be used the following regular expression could be used.

```
(?:^|,)[^,|]*(\|{2,})(?=[^,|]*(?:,|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E195Zj/2/)

The strings of interest are held in capture group 1 for each match.

Comment: That works very well. Thank you very much. I am using Java regular expression in the Nifi processors. Do you know what I can replace \K with to comply with the Java regular expression?

Comment: I've made a small change and will provide an explanation. Have you confirmed `\K` is supported?

Comment: No, \K is not supported. I am trying to look for an equivalent replacement

Comment: A variable length negative lookbehind would be an alternative, but I don't believe that's supported by Java either. Could you use a capture group instead?

Comment: I added an alternative without `\K` that employs a capture group, should that be helpful.